# Why program shows empty result?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I create data field name `"csPreRequest"` and add to html form as model attribute like follow.

```
@GetMapping("/add")
public String addNewCourse(Model model) {

    String csPreRequest = "";
    model.addAttribute("csPreRequest",csPreRequest);

    return  "admin/add-course-module";
}
```

what i need to do is fill this field with my custom data and return back to controller class.I tried as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String addNewCourse(@ModelAttribute("csPreRequest") String course) {

    System.out.println("\n Pre Reqest Courses : "+course+"\n\n");   

    return "redirect:/courses/add";
}
```

and my html code is like this:

```
      <input type="text" id="csPreRequest" th:field="${csPreRequest}">
```

my program work fines but nothing prints for result. what's went wrong here?

Comment: How are you running the code, do you know where the console is that is supposed to print it?

Comment: Provide a value for csPreRequest and check. As you are providing an empty string, that is causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your GetMapping you're setting the model attribute with the variable `csPreRequest` which you initialized as an empty string, and an empty string is what gets rendered.

What you should be doing is:
1. When `POST /save` is called, then the value passed should be persisted.
2. When `GET /add` is called, it should retrieve the value persisted and set in the model.

Comment: what i ask is i need to assign value from forntend and getting that value to controller. my problem is that assign value lost in controller

Comment: Yes because you have two different endpoints each with its own scope, whatever you set in your post request is gone once you reach the end of controller method unless you persisted it

Answer (score 0):

You should try `@RequestParam` when return back to controller:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String addNewCourse( @RequestParam("csPreRequest") String course ) {

    System.out.println("\n Pre Reqest Courses : "+course+"\n\n");   

    return "redirect:/courses/add";

}
```